# How do I export an xcode project for transferring to another mac machine

Tags: xcode

Am doing iphone Apple Applcation. Am using Xcode 4.2. but my iphone is ios 5.1 version so i need to use xcode 4.3.3.Already i have developed the application in xcode 4.2. but now i need to run that application in xcode 4.3.3 so how to export the project from xcode 4.2?
Please guide me for this otherwise i need to develop application again.

Answer (score 1):

From XCode 4.2 to Xcode 4.3.3, you only need to open the same project with the different XCode version, done. No export or complicated stuff needed

Comment: Just open the other Xcode version, and then look for your project.

Comment: i didn't upgrade the version. i just move my xcode projects from one mac to another mac.

Comment: oh god. i developed the iphone application in xcode 4.2 now i have installed new mac in another PC and i installed xcode 4.3 also. now i need to open my old project which i have done in xcode 4.2. for this i need to copy the project from xcode 4.2 Mac PC to xcode 4.3 Mac PC. how to do this?

Comment: (1) Get a USB stick. (2) Copy your project's folder onto the USB stick (3) put USB stick into second mac (4) Copy project folder onto second mac (5) Click on XCode project file

Comment: Great explanation deanWombourne. but i just compress the project folder and send to my mail then i download my project from my mail, then i run the application means some iamges are missing.

Comment: Then go back and copy the images too

Comment: That means you images are probably not in your project's folder, which might cause problems in the future - I would make sure that everything you need to build the app is inside one folder (and subfolders of course!). To fix this I would move the images on the first mac, fix Xcode so the project still builds and then copy it to the second mac again.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information to @George Aguirre answer

From XCode 4.2 to Xcode 4.3.3, you only need to open the same project with the different XCode version, done. No export or complicated stuff needed. You can compress "your application folder" and then save some where and then uncompress it and do necessary changes in new Xcode 4.3 setting if required and you are good to go.

Comment: if i finished the project means it saved in desktop, is it my project folder or it may saved in any other place?

Comment: I was talking about your project folder. Just compress that and you will be good.

Comment: ya that only i did. i just compress the project and send to my mail, then i just download the compressed project in my mail from another PC, then if i run means images are missing.